# How can i delete using ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have a image gallery inside a `<div>` which contains 10 photos. How can i delete them using ajax? I want one cross sign to appear at the top right corner of each photo and when user clicks on it, the image should get deleted. And the whole `<div>` should get refreshed. I do know working with jquery ajax. But is there any plugin available in Jquery that can this visually appealing?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery: use the `something.remove()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

DOM: use the `parent.removeChild(something)` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Comment: If you actually want the image to stay deleted on reload you'll need to set some sort of flag somewhere.  Or have a script elsewhere to delete it from your db, etc.

Comment: For what you want visually, just overlay some X button that binds to a click event that calls `.remove` on the image (well, the container holding the image and X button).

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually wanting to delete the image from the server, or from the page so that other viewers will no longer see it, then you will need to have a server URI that deletes the resource. This can be called from JavaScript, but needs a server action.